# Путь для скрипта DML и DDL в URL-адресе jdbc при подключении к базе данных H2

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

Я прочитал в учебнике H2, что я могу автоматически выполнять команды DDL или DML, когда клиент подключается к базе данных следующим образом:

```
   `String url = "jdbc: h2: mem: test; INIT = runscript from '~ / create.sql'` \\; runscript from '~ / init.sql'";
```

но я не могу понять, как мне указать свой путь вместо '~ / create.sql', учитывая, что я использую структуру maven в своем проекте, а мой sql-скрипт находится в

```
  \src\test\resources\creationTables.sql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В H2 можно указать, чтоб скрипт брался из classpath, а `src/test/resources` добавляется в `classpath`, когда запускаются тесты (а `src/main/resources` добавляется всегда - и для тестов и для обычного кода).

Укажите jdbc url в таком виде:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:sample;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:/creationTables.sql'
```

Comment: спасибо! теперь ясно!